# Am I using libav in my code? License matters

Tags: opencv, licensing, libav

I work on a commercial application using opencv. I know I use libopencv_highgui.so but I'm not sure I need [libav](https://libav.org/legal/) in my binary since it is not mentionned in the binary:

```
objdump -p <binary>
```

Result:

```
NEEDED               libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4
NEEDED               libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
NEEDED               libopencv_core.so.2.4
NEEDED               libinteractive_markers.so
NEEDED               libimage_loader.so
NEEDED               libtf.so
NEEDED               libroscpp.so
NEEDED               libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0
NEEDED               librosconsole.so
NEEDED               libroscpp_serialization.so
NEEDED               librostime.so
NEEDED               libboost_system.so.1.58.0
NEEDED               libyaml-cpp.so.0.5
NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
NEEDED               libm.so.6
NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
NEEDED               libc.so.6
```

No mention of the libav at all, hence, is everything ok?

I had a doubt and started checking libopencv_highgui.so

```
objdump -p libopencv_highgui.so
```

I got this:

```
Dynamic Section:
  ...
  NEEDED               libavcodec.so.54
  NEEDED               libavformat.so.54
  NEEDED               libavutil.so.52
```

Does it mean I use libopencv_highgui.so but my binary doesn't need libav or I'm not checking properly?

Thanks

Comment: On a sidenote, I'm not sure libav itself is a problem, only if you use x264 or similar proprietary codecs within it

Comment: Yep, I saw this in the point 17 of the link to libav. It's still not 100% clear to me tho

Comment: opencv can be built without ffmpeg. But libav is not a problem.